# Unable to install composer

Tags: php, dll, pdo, composer-php

I am unable to install composer on my local system. Following are my local system and PHP details:

OS - Windows 8.1 Pro - 64 Bit OS - X84- based processor

I have installed XAMPP  -
PHP Version 5.6.8.

On trying to install composer, it requested PHP_pdo.dll. However, I downloaded the dll and placed it into the xampp/PHP/ext folder

But seems some versioning issue. Where can I get PHP_pdo.dll for PHP Version 5.6.8 VC11 X84?

Comment: In your php.ini, is `extension=php_pdo.dll` commented out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

composer is installed using the PHP CLI (Command Line Interface)

The `php.ini` that controls the CLI is in your `\xampp\php` folder (its not the same one that controls PHP under Apache).

Edit `\xampp\php\php.ini` and make sure that

```
extension=php_pdo.dll
```

is not commented out, a comment has a `#` in column 1

That said, you had better get the original `php_pdo.dll` back that was in `xampp\php\ext` as there is no way of knowing if you put a good or bad new version in when you did whatever you did with the new one